# Serverless deploy package

Tags: serverless, aws-serverless

I am trying to bypass the package step and uses the existing package to deploy and update CloudFormation stacks.

I have created serverless package by using following command:

```
serverless package --package package
```

Got package directory with the following files

```
cloudformation-template-create-stack.json
cloudformation-template-update-stack.json
service-api.zip
serverless-state.json
```

Trying to deploy with following command:

```
SLS_DEBUG=* serverless deploy --package package
```

getting below error

> ServerlessError: This command can only be run in a Serverless service directory. Make sure to reference a valid config file in the current working directory if you're using a custom config file
> at PluginManager.validateServerlessConfigDependency (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:546:15)
> at PluginManager.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:474:10)
> at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:524:24

I have tried with copy serverless.yml into package directory, But no luck

Answer (score 0):

Please execute

```
SLS_DEBUG=* serverless deploy --package package
```

from the directory where you've serverless.yml file. It should work.

From the name of the file it looks like you've mis-spelled `serveless.yml`. Please rename it to `serverless.yml`.